# Set Up a Server for Small Web Sockets Tutorial

Tags: javascript, websocket, server, socket.io

I want to put together a small project for my team to introduce people to web sockets. I am new to web sockets myself so I have to learn about it all first. My idea was to create a small bare bones chat app where people can:

1. Download my repo of a small app with basic UI that takes in chat messages.
2. Allow users to type in messages and see their messages pop up in the chat window on the app along with messages anyone else sends.
3. There will be 3 teams so each team will download the repo, run it locally and chat with each other over web sockets.

The exercise itself is people will implement the methods for creating a web socket connection with a server that facilitates the conversation. My issue is that I don't know of a good, basic free way to host a small server. I am literally just trying to host something like the below to enable conversation. What is a good way to host this so I can achieve what I'm hoping to? Is it even possible to do something like this when people are running the program locally?

EDIT: each time will be remote, so running locally unfortunately won't work.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A user connected');

  // Handle events from connected clients
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log('Received message:', data);
    // Broadcast the message to all connected clients
    io.emit('message', data);
  });

  // Handle disconnection of clients
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('A user disconnected');
  });
});

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: If this is for use in a classroom, then any PC in the classroom can act as the Host..

Comment: Good point, although I should have mentioned that each team is remote, so I'll need to find a real online host.

Comment: @Andrew Colin - I used to host my nodejs apps to heroku that offered free tier, but sadly they ended  that. You can check this link to find some others that still provide free tier [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/heroku-alternatives-deploy-node-js-app/#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20Heroku%20announced%20plans%20to,using%20Heroku%20for%20deploying%20apps.)